# is it possible to integrate a chatter news feed from two seperate orgs?

Tags: chatter, org

the senario is that we want to be able to have a 3rd party supplier share post and info from their SF org with users on our internal SF org.

I woulld like to know more about the different options are to do this and the pros/cons of each.

many thanks